# Child Process Fork-what do I write on the client to bring the results back to the client? How can I display these on localhost:3000?

Tags: java, excel, meteor

I have written code to upload an excel file and execute a java application using Meteor.  When I execute the Java application with child process, the results go into the command prompt.  (I am using child process spawn.) I want the results to go onto localhost:3000/Applications. (I have created Applications with iron router. It is a separate page from the file upload page.)  I have tried child process fork but I don't know how to call the results to the client.  I assume that I have to call the fork results in the client code, like through a template.  I can not find anything on this.  Do I need a pipe?  Do I need to use something different?  I can give a little more detail. When the Java application executes, it is supposed to read the excel file. In order to make this happen, I used an on click method after the file is uploaded to grab the file, using (session.set and session.get) and called a meteor method that executes the child process.  At this point, the method executes and sends the file name and the java application to the command prompt.  I need the results to pop up on my localhost and not the command prompt. I am very close to finishing the application and have done extensive research, but because I am new to programming, I am having trouble putting the pieces together. Thank you Thank you! I appreciate you taking the time to read this!
Server Javascript Code:

```
    Router.configure({
        layoutTemplate: 'main'
    });
    YourFileCollection = new FS.Collection("yourFileCollection", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("yourFileCollection", {path:   "~/meteor_uploads"})]
});
YourFileCollection.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  update: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  download: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  }
});
Meteor.methods({
    'kickoffJar': function(selectedFile){
        console.log("kickoffJar");
        console.log(selectedFile);
        var child = require('child_process').spawn("Java", ['-  jar','C:/\Users/\caitl/\HelloWorld.jar'],);
        child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('stdout: ' + data);
            //Here is where the output goes
});
    child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
        //Here is where the error output goes
});
    child.on('close', function(code) {
        console.log('closing code: ' + code);
        //Here you can get the exit code of the script
});
}
});
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'fileList',
    template: 'fileList'
});
```

Client Javascript Code:

```
Router.configure({  
    layoutTemplate: 'main'
});
YourFileCollection = new FS.Collection("yourFileCollection", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("yourFileCollection", {path:    "~/meteor_uploads"})]
});
YourFileCollection.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  update: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  download: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  }
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Meteor.subscribe("fileUploads");
  Template.fileList.helpers({
    theFiles: function () {
      return YourFileCollection.find();
    }
  });

  Template.fileList.events({
    'click #deleteFileButton ': function (event) {
      console.log("deleteFile button ", this);
      YourFileCollection.remove({_id: this._id});
    },
    'click #validateFileButton ': function (event){
        Session.set('selectedFile', ({_id: this._id}));
        Session.get('selectedFile');
        var selectedFile = Session.get('selectedFile')
        Meteor.call ('kickoffJar', selectedFile, function (error, result) {
            if(error){  
            alert('Error');
            }else{
            Router.go('/Application');
            }
});
},
    'click #openFileButton ': function (event){
        Router.go('/Application');          
 },
    'change .your-upload-class': function (event, template) {
      console.log("uploading...")
      FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function (file) {
        console.log("each file...");
        var yourFile = new FS.File(file);
        YourFileCollection.insert(yourFile, function (err, fileObj) {
          console.log("callback for the insert, err: ", err);
          if (!err) {
            console.log("inserted without error");
          }
          else {
            console.log("there was an error", err);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("fileUploads", function () {
    console.log("publishing fileUploads");
    return YourFileCollection.find();
  });
}
Router.route('/Application');
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'fileList',
    template: 'fileList'
});
```

Client HTML

## Application

{{> yield}}

---

Home

```
<template name="fileList">
    <br/>Testing file upload below<br/><br/>
  <input class="your-upload-class" type="file">
  <br/><br/>


  <table border="1">
    <tbody>
      {{#each theFiles}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{uploadedAt}}</td><td>{{original.name}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{url}}">link</a></td><td>{{#if     isUploaded}}uploaded{{else}}uploading...{{/if}}</td>
    <td><button id="deleteFileButton">delete</button></td>
    <td><button id="validateFileButton">validate</button></td>
    <td><button id="openFileButton">Open</button></td>     
    </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
<template name="Application">
    <h2>Application</h2>
</template>
```

Comment: I believe that posting here code will help to resolve the problem

Comment: @crobar Please edit your question and insert your code there. To display it as code, just put four spaces at the beginning of the line

Comment: Thank you!  I edited it and it should all be there now. The only thing this doesn't show is the packages.  Thank you again everyone!  I so appreciate your help!